# jQuery AJAX will not load inside <select>

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".region").load('getRecords.php?start=regions');

});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<select>

            <div class="region"></div>          

</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I put this list inside the `<select>` tags, it is totally not displaying... When I take it outside the `<select>` tags I get...

```
    <option value="Central Asia">Central Asia</option>
    <option value="Central Europe">Central Europe</option>
    <option value="East Africa">East Africa</option>
    <option value="East Asia">East Asia</option>
```

Anybody have this problem? I can't find a solution to it anywhere.

This function works fine with this XMLHttpRequest function I made, but I found out today when some lady at work was trying to register with Internet Explorer, that it doesn't work with it. Blegh. So, I am making the switch to jQuery, and it burns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `<div>` inside a `<select>`. Just put the class on the `<select>`.

```
<select class="region"></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

`select` elements cannot have `div` elements as children.  They can only have `option` and `optgroup` elements as children ([see HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)).  What happens when you put a `div` inside a `select` (and particularly when you give the `div` `option` elements as children) is up to the browser.

Try loading them into the `select` instead: give that element the class instead:

```
<select class="region"></select>
```